# C++ Inherited Stack-Allocated Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 2 classes, A and B (B is a subclass of A)

Q: Is it possible to have a stack-allocated array in A that I can initialise in B? And how would I do that?

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

class A {
public:
    uint8_t buffer[0];
}

class B : public A {
public:
    uint8_t buffer[800] = { /* ... */ };
}
```

What I've currently got is this:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

class A {
public:
    uint8_t* buffer;
    A(uint8_t* buffer_) : buffer(buffer_) {}
}

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A(new uint8_t[800]{ /* ... */ }) {}
}
```

I've currently got it working with pointers, but it'd be nice to be able to have it stack-allocated, as speed is key, and also it's a fairly large array that would be better initialised at compile time, cause unless I'm very much mistaken that is what happens with stack-allocated arrays

Comment: Yes. Please be more specific.

Comment: "Fairly large" and stack allocated are a bad combination, because the stack is rather small.

Comment: The questions is very unclear. Show your code with pointers, then we might be able to tell you more.

Comment: If something is defined in class `A`, then it is initialized in class `A` (when its instance is constructed). But you can assign the values later.

Comment: Things on stack are not initialized at compile time. Static variables might be initialized at compile-time. `constexpr`s maybe, and `consteval` for sure. As the stack is used for local variables, they can be initialized at run-time only (when the resp. scope is entered aka. the resp. function is called).

Comment: @Scheff Oh right, must've got a little confused, thanks

Comment: How often / how frequently is `B` instanced? If it happens only once, I immediately would stop to be concerned about the `new[]`. Heap alloc might be more expensive but it doesn't make sense to care about this if that happens one time only (because the rest of the application will probably consume much more time in relation to this.)

Comment: Sidenote to the first piece of code, as I'm not sure what you intend to do: `A::buffer` and `B::buffer` are seperate entities, you can't "override" variables like this and you can't change the size of `A::buffer` through inheritance.

Comment: @Scheff It would usually only be instanced once. I know it doesn't really make sense to care so much in that case, but I would like to know how to do this

Comment: If you want to go the first way, make a member pointer in `class A`, make a member array in `class B` and pass the address of the array (in `class B`) as an constructor argument in `class A`. To pass the size as well would make sense because otherwise `A` cannot know it.

Comment: @churill Yes, the first piece of code is more to show sort of what I'm going for, I know that's not how to do it. Oh so you can't change the size of an array through inheritance? Okay then, seems like what I'm going for is impossible. Thanks

Comment: @Scheff Ah that's a really good idea, thanks for that, I think I may do that

Comment: Scheff's solution is pretty good, just there will be an additional pointer stored in the class. An alternative solution might be to pass the initialization list via constructors of `A` and `B`, something as, simplified: https://godbolt.org/z/nbhfrj. You can also check that the compiler benefits from knowing the initialization values at compile time: https://godbolt.org/z/sfr9qh.

Comment: @DanielLangr I can deal with an additional pointer - Your solution does sound/look good though, especially for situations where memory conservation is critical

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a stack-allocated array in A that I can initialise in B?

Yes, if `A` is an aggregate.

> And how would I do that?

Like this for example:

```
struct A {
    uint8_t buffer[100];
};

struct B : A {
    B(): A {
        .buffer = {
            // the initialisers for buffer
        },
    } {}
};
```

> Unfortunately I'm wanting to have a different array size in each subclass of A

Then that array cannot be a member of the same base because the size of a member is constant. Thus what you want is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm wanting to have a different array size in each subclass of A, so that doesn't really work for me - Thanks though I didn't know you could do that

Comment: @WilliamBanks See edit.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for explaining - I should've known that really